# How to make .NET 6.0 Hot Reload work on the simplest "Hello, World" console application?

Tags: c#, .net, hot-reload, visual-studio-2022

Consider this C# 10 / .NET 6.0 / Visual Studio 2022 "Hello, World" console application:

```cs
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information

foreach (int _ in Enumerable.Range(0, 100))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
    Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
}
```

If I run this program with debugging, or without debugging, changing the `World` to `Earth` and then saving the file and clicking "Hot Reload" (Apply Code Changes) button does nothing. The program continues to write to console `Hello, World!`.

I can force the application to change the string without restarting **without** using Hot Reload, by using [Edit and Continue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/edit-and-continue?view=vs-2022) instead, i.e. by making changes while the application is in break mode.

I did enable all the options for Hot Reload:

[image]

Why doesn't the Hot Reload work? Am I doing something wrong? This [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-hot-reload/) states it should also work for Console apps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you change `Task.Delay(1000).Wait()` to `await Task.Delay(1000)` then hot reload on save will work. It seems when a thread is blocked, hot reload doesn't want to work.